# Verificar si una caja de texto tiene algo escrito, Python

Tags: python, string, tkinter

Buen dia, Estoy teniendo un problema con algo pequeño que no logro completarlo. Basicamente quiero verificar si hay algo escrito en una caja de texto ya sea A 2 # @ o un espacios.

Intente con la validacion de cadenas pero esta siempre se marca aunque no haya nada escrito.

todos estos dan True aunque no haya nada escrito dentro de la caja de texto(tkinter) que utilizo

```
type(a) = type('')
type(a) = str
isinstance(a,str)
str(a) = a
```

Lo que yo busco es que si no lleva nada escrito me dea False, Pero si hay algo escrito me dea True

Comment: qué es `a` en este contexto? Un `Stringvar`? El widget de la caja de texto? Ayudaría mucho que muestres cómo lo creas, y aún más si provees un ejemplo reproducible!

Comment: @DannyTalent , Gracias por responder. Si es un `StringVar`, Felizmente le di solución a mi problemita, Contando el numero de letras de la cadena con `len` y comparandolo a 0, `len(a) >>0`. De igual forma gracias por responder!

Comment: okay, pero para que tengas en cuenta, si quieres sacar el texto de un `StringVar` es `a.get()`, si solo sacas `a`, obtienes el <<objeto>>, no el contenido. Si `len` te funciona bien, a lo mejor es porque tiene un wrapper para la función...